# Is there a way to namespace custom web components?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, web-component

I am creating various web components for a website. I can manage them each individually, but is there a way to combine them all in a single file and call that one JS file?

Then in my HTML, reference the components as I need them?

Comment: sounds like vue.js.

Comment: This is not for vue.js. This is for vanilla js web components.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, yes, you could put all the web components into a single file and reference that one file. I would also suggest that you add something to the front or back of each of your components tag name so that if you want to use other components, there are no collisions.

For example, let's say you create a combo-box component. Calling the tag combo-box could cause collisions with other web components called combo-box, however, if you called it mm-combo-box or combo-box-mm, chances of collisions would be much lower.

Comment: The issue I'm running into is with the template. Having multiple templates in the file is creating some significant errors.

Comment: Can you elaborate?